# Making a post request to server using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, post, http-post

I am trying to create some data and throw it into a url just to verify working knowledge of using post method in angular. The url I am using is 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' which comes from 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'. On the main page it says all Http methods are supported. I am trying to submit some simply data throw a form that I have created following a tutorial online. When I go to refresh the url, my data does not appear with the rest that is already there, does anyone know why I am not able to create or send any? I have attached my component and template.

```
<h1>Post API in Angular</h1>
<form #signupForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(signupForm.value)">
    <input type="text" name="userId" ngModel placeholder="User ID"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="id" ngModel placeholder="ID"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="title" ngModel placeholder="Title"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="body" ngModel placeholder="Body"><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit Data</button>
</form>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})


export class PostComponent {
  private url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  myData: any[];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    http.get(this.url)
      .subscribe(response=>{
        this.myData = response as any[];
      })
  } 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
  submit(data){
    this.http.post(this.url, data)
      .subscribe(result=>{
        console.log("Result", result);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: `When I go to refresh the url, my data does not appear with the rest that is already there` - If you reload the site you also reload the app, losing any unsaved data. Are you aware of this?

Comment: I still don't get the question. Is your POST success or it gives you an error? Where's the GET method to retrieve the data you want?

Comment: No error, just not seeing the data I input into the form show up with the other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API backend at jsonplaceholder.typicode.com doesn't store your form data. So http.get() will return always just [the posts in here](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts), and nothing more.

On the [guide](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/) at *Create a resource* section there is a remark:

```
Important: resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if.
```